# How do I get the text value of a default selected option

Tags: forms, bitrix

```
<select name="ORDER_PROP_14" id="ORDER_PROP_14">
  <option value="24">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="48">Nederland</option>
</select>


    <?php if ( isset($arUser['PERSONAL_COUNTRY']) || !empty($arUser['PERSONAL_COUNTRY']) ) { ?>
        <?php if ( $arUser['PERSONAL_COUNTRY'] != 0 ) { ?>
        $("#ORDER_PROP_14 option[value=<?=$arUser['PERSONAL_COUNTRY']?>]").prop('selected', true);
        $("#ORDER_PROP_14").siblings('span').html(<?=$arUser['PERSONAL_COUNTRY']?>);
        <?php } else { ?>
        $("#ORDER_PROP_14 option[value=48]").prop('selected', true);
        $("#ORDER_PROP_14").siblings('span').html(48);  
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        $("#ORDER_PROP_14 option[value=48]").prop('selected', true);
        $("#ORDER_PROP_14").siblings('span').html(48);
    <?php } ?>
```

I tried using this code but it seems to be no used.

```
$( "#ORDER_PROP_14 option:selected" ).text();
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should conclude js in `<script></script>`, and before use `jquery($.)` check that `jquery.js` lib was included.

Something like this:

```
<span></span>
<select name="ORDER_PROP_14" id="ORDER_PROP_14">
  <option value="24">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="48">Nederland</option>
</select>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    <?php if ( isset($arUser['PERSONAL_COUNTRY']) || !empty($arUser['PERSONAL_COUNTRY']) ) { ?>
        <?php if ( $arUser['PERSONAL_COUNTRY'] != 0 ) { ?>
        $("#ORDER_PROP_14 option[value=<?=$arUser['PERSONAL_COUNTRY']?>]").prop('selected', true);
        $("#ORDER_PROP_14").siblings('span').html(<?=$arUser['PERSONAL_COUNTRY']?>);
        <?php } else { ?>
        $("#ORDER_PROP_14 option[value=48]").prop('selected', true);
        $("#ORDER_PROP_14").siblings('span').html(48);  
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        $("#ORDER_PROP_14 option[value=48]").prop('selected', true);
        $("#ORDER_PROP_14").siblings('span').html(48);
    <?php } ?>
</script>
```